Can absolute silence exist and how are thermal and quantum noise a limit?
For my exam, I must answer the question: can absolute silence exist? While doing research, I obviously heard about noises internal to our body and noises external to our environment but I also heard about thermal noises and quantum noises. What are these noises and what is the difference between thermal and quantum noise? Furthermore, are these noises audible to humans?

Well, I guess you could consider absolute silence to exist in space where “there is no matter”. However, I believe there is some matter in space although extremely sparse. I am not an expert on the matter though so hopefully someone can hop on and lend a hand here. The point here I guess is to define “absolute”. If space counts as “empty space” then I guess you could say that absolute silence does exist. Otherwise, I would think that it does not in an objective sense. That being said psychoacoustics not taken into account...

Thermal noise and quantum noise are entirely unrelated to audible "noise". The terminology comes from an information-theoretical point of view, where one must distinguish between "signal" and "noise" in an incoming stream. "signal" in this case signifies whatever information one is trying to extract, while "noise" signifies any external influence there might be. Thermal and quantum "noise" are therefore effects of thermodynamics and vacuum fluctuations which can "pollute" measurements to some extent. I suppose they could be made audible by a measurement which is sensitive enough to detect them, and then converting the data from the measurement into sound, but they are definetely not audible to human ears as-is.
Without any further information about which course your exam is for, or any formal definition of "silence" (let alone what the word "absolute" means in this context), your question is impossible to answer. But in general, I would interpret "absolute silence" to mean no sound at all, meaning no oscillations in a medium. This is impossible to achieve in practice, however, one can approximate it to almost arbitrary degree by simply creating a vacuum, in which there is no medium for sound to propagate. One could argue that even if a source of sound was placed in such a vacuum and isolated, the vacuum would be "absolutely silent".
